# How to use if else statement inside div content in ajax after response

Tags: jquery, node.js, ajax, express, ejs

How can I use if else statement inside div content.
after success function()
I'm getting the user profile image from back-end.
If user profile image exists then select that
else select default.
Now the problem is I have several div content layout inside that I would like to use if-else statement

I have tried this, but it does't work..

```
success: function(response) {
  if (response != '') {
    var $view_feeds_by = document.getElementById("view_feeds_by");
    $view_feeds_by.innerHTML = "";

    const post_data = response.feeds_data;
    for (var i = 0, len = post_data.length; i < len; i++) {
      $view_feeds_by.innerHTML = $view_feeds_by.innerHTML + `<div class="card mb-3">` +
        ` <div class="row"> ` +
        ` <div class="col-10" style="padding-left:50px;padding-top:20px"> ` +
        ` <div class="d-flex bd-highlight"> `
      if (post_data[i].User.user_profile_pic) {
        ` <div class="img_cont"> ` +
          ` <img src="../public/profile_image/${post_data[i].User.user_profile_pic}" class="rounded-circle user_img"> ` +
          ` </div> `
      } else {
        ` <div class="img_cont"><img src="../public/profile_image/icon.jpg" class="rounded-circle user_img"></div> `
      }
      ` </div> ` +
      ` </div> ` +
      ` </div> ` +
      ` </div> `;
    }
  }
}
```

Something Like this...

```
<div class="card mb-3">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-10" style="padding-left:50px;padding-top:20px">
      <div class="d-flex bd-highlight">
        <% if(item.User.user_profile_pic){ %>
        <div class="img_cont">
          <img src="../public/profile_image/<%= item.User.user_profile_pic %>" class="rounded-circle user_img">
        </div>
        <% } else { %>
          <div class="img_cont"><img src="../public/profile_image/icon.jpg" class="rounded-circle user_img"></div>
        <% } %>
      </div>
    </div> 
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just store the entire string in a variable and set `.innerHTML = yourvariable`

```
success: function(response) {
  if (response != '') {
    var $view_feeds_by = document.getElementById("view_feeds_by");
    let innerHTML = ''

    const post_data = response.feeds_data;
    for (var i = 0, len = post_data.length; i < len; i++) {
      innerHTML += `<div class="card mb-3">
      <div class="row"> 
      <div class="col-10" style="padding-left:50px;padding-top:20px">
      <div class="d-flex bd-highlight">`;
      if (post_data[i].User.user_profile_pic) {
        innerHTML += ` <div class="img_cont"> 
          <img src="../public/profile_image/${post_data[i].User.user_profile_pic}" class="rounded-circle user_img"> 
        </div> `
      } else {
        innerHTML += ` <div class="img_cont"><img src="../public/profile_image/icon.jpg" class="rounded-circle user_img"></div> `
      }
      innerHTML += ` </div>
      </div>
      </div>
      </div>`;
    }
    $view_feeds_by.innerHTML = innerHTML;
  }
}
```

**Note:** You don't need to concat template literals **`..`** with `+`, it supports newlines.

Comment: Thank you so much..! It worked.                                                                             Is there any way that after success funtion() in ajax clinet-side,                           
ejs (template) can be called and then pass the response to ejs (template) like how we can reder a page and pass data.                                                                    
For example..                                                                                
res.render('home',{title:'home',user:userdata});

Comment: Please feel free to post this question separately as others can help you effectively. Meanwhile if this answer solved the current problem mark the answer as accepted (the gray tick) so that others can find it useful.

Comment: I have marked it as accepted. Since I'm new to stackoverflow and my reputation is below 15 that's why it's not reflecting but it's has been recorded by the stackovrflow.